# Angular 2 Dart - Dynamic Routing

Tags: dart, angular, angular-dart, angular2-routing

Im working in Angular 2 Dart, but I should be able to translate any JS or TS examples.

1) **How can I gain a list of all the registered routes?**

2) **How can I delete a route from the registered routes?**

I know I can dynamically add via something like this:

```
  ...
  final Router router;

  AppComponent(this.router){
    this.router.config([
      Route(path: '/Page-0', component: Page0Route, name: 'Page-0')
    ]);
  }
  ...
```

But yet to work out listing and removing routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no official way. The `RouteRegistry` contains the configured routes but it doesn't provide public members to access them and in Dart you can't access private fields like you can in TypeScript to work around this limitation.

The only workaround that I see is to extend the `RouteRegistry` class and add your custom implementation as provider for the `RouteRegistry` type, after `ROUTE_PROVIDERS` to ensure your custom implementation is taken instead.
I haven't tried this yet though.

Comment: Bummer. Does this include deleting routes?

Comment: I haven't seen anything related to deleting routes. The router is work in progress though. There are many feature requests they consider implementing. I had the impression there is at least one issue that covers your question partially but wasn't able to find it.